# cleared cmos and now computer restarts when windows is starting up

Tags: windows, boot, reboot, cmos

I cleared the cmos as suggested for some problem that I had with hardware and changed the RAM place to another slot, and now windows wont start, it goes till the message WINDOWS IS STARTING (I use windows 7) and then restarts, when I choose the option to fix the problems or start windows normally it wont fix the problem. Maybe I missed something when I cleared the CMOS because after that all I did is changed the date and time do I need to do anything else because it asks me to enter to BIOS SETUP UTILITY.

Comment: Be sure the settings you are using match the settings when Windows was installed.

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to boot an OS after making memory changes until you confirm that the memory is working reliably. You risk corrupting your OS installation.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, during boot press `F8` to enter `Advanced Boot Options Menu` and select `Disable automatic restart on system failure` and press `Enter`. [BSOD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Screen_of_Death) will tell you what is wrong with your system. My guess is that the current SATA AHCI setting is different from what is was before the CMOS clear and during Windows installation.